# What are all of the SSH Key files?

Tags: ssh, openssh

There are six key files in `/etc/ssh` directory for private and public keys. 4 of them are for DSA and RSA public & private keys. but there are two more files named `ssh_host_key` and `ssh_host_key.pub`, what are these keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh_host_key` is the private key if you use the SSHv1 protocol and `ssh_host_key.pub` is the matching public key.
It should be a RSA key.

If you use SSHv2 you chose between multiple signing algorithms like DSA, RSA and ECDSA and then the `ssh_host_ecdsa_key` and etc are used.